# tar -u ads files insteed of update them

Tags: linux, tar

I'm using

```
tar cvf /path/name.tar --exclude='*/_files/cache/*' /home/a/
```

to create tar archive and

```
tar uvf /path/name.tar --exclude='*/_files/cache/*' /home/a/
```

to update (add new/changed files) but every time I execute it, all files are added again and my name.tar file is bigger. How to changed update files insteed of add another copy of them to archive?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92775/tar-u-operation

Comment: This question is about using software rather than programming and it is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [su] or [unix.se] would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MrTux solution is to add --delete :

```
tar uvf --delete /path/name.tar --exclude='*/_files/cache/*' /home/a/
```